# Linear programming salad mixture optimization with PuLP

Tags: python, optimization, linear-programming, pulp

I've set up the following LP problem and everything appears to be working except for my percent of mass constraint for salad greens.  I want the mass of salad greens to be at least 40%, but I'm getting a syntax error with PuLP's `lpSum`, and I'm not sure how to reconcile it.

I'm have the following constraints for each salad:

 At least 15 grams of protein

 At least 2 and at most 8 grams of fat

 At least 4 grams of carbohydrates

 At most 200 milligrams of sodium

 At least 40% leafy greens by mass.

```
from pulp import *

# Creates a list of the Ingredients
Ingredients = ['TOMATO', 'LETTUCE', 'SPINACH', 'CARROT', 'SUNFLOWER', 'TOFU', 'CHICKPEAS', 'OIL']

kcal = {'TOMATO': 21, 
         'LETTUCE': 16, 
         'SPINACH': 40, 
         'CARROT': 41, 
         'SUNFLOWER': 585, 
         'TOFU': 120,
         'CHICKPEAS': 164,
         'OIL': 884}

protein = {'TOMATO': 0.85, 
         'LETTUCE': 1.62, 
         'SPINACH': 2.86, 
         'CARROT': 0.93, 
         'SUNFLOWER': 23.4, 
         'TOFU': 16,
         'CHICKPEAS': 9,
         'OIL': 0}

fat = {'TOMATO': 0.33, 
         'LETTUCE': 0.20, 
         'SPINACH': 0.39, 
         'CARROT': 0.24, 
         'SUNFLOWER': 48.7, 
         'TOFU': 5.0,
         'CHICKPEAS': 2.6,
         'OIL': 100.0}

carbs = {'TOMATO': 4.64, 
         'LETTUCE': 2.37, 
         'SPINACH': 3.63, 
         'CARROT': 9.58, 
         'SUNFLOWER': 15.0, 
         'TOFU': 3.0,
         'CHICKPEAS': 27.0,
         'OIL': 0.0}

sodium = {'TOMATO': 9.0, 
         'LETTUCE': 28.0, 
         'SPINACH': 65.0, 
         'CARROT': 69.0, 
         'SUNFLOWER': 3.80, 
         'TOFU': 120.0,
         'CHICKPEAS': 78.0,
         'OIL': 0.0}

cost = {'TOMATO': 1.0, 
         'LETTUCE': 0.75, 
         'SPINACH': 0.50, 
         'CARROT': 0.50, 
         'SUNFLOWER': 0.45, 
         'TOFU': 2.15,
         'CHICKPEAS': 0.95,
         'OIL': 2.00}

# Create the 'prob' variable to contain the problem data
prob = LpProblem("The Salad Problem", LpMinimize)

# A dictionary called 'ingredient_vars' is created to contain the referenced Variables
ingredient_vars = LpVariable.dicts("Ingr",Ingredients,0)

# The objective function is added to 'prob' first
prob += lpSum([kcal[i]*ingredient_vars[i] for i in Ingredients]), "Total kCal of Ingredients per salad"

# The constraints are added to 'prob'
prob += lpSum([protein[i] * ingredient_vars[i] for i in Ingredients]) >= 15.0, "ProteinRequirement"
prob += 8.0 >= lpSum([fat[i] * ingredient_vars[i] for i in Ingredients]) >= 2.0, "FatRequirement"
prob += lpSum([carbs[i] * ingredient_vars[i] for i in Ingredients]) >= 4.0, "CarbRequirement"
prob += lpSum([sodium[i] * ingredient_vars[i] for i in Ingredients]) <= 200.0, "SodiumRequirement"
prob += lpSum(prob.variables()[2].varValue + prob.variables()[4].varValue) / lpSum([prob.variables()[i].varValue for i in range(8)]) >= 0.40, "GreensRequirement"

prob.solve()

# The status of the solution is printed to the screen
print("Status:", LpStatus[prob.status])

# Each of the variables is printed with it's resolved optimum value
for v in prob.variables():
    print(v.name, "=", v.varValue)

# The optimised objective function value is printed to the screen
print("Total kCal of Ingredients per salad = ", value(prob.objective))
```

This is the constraint that's giving me the issue:

```
prob += lpSum(prob.variables()[2].varValue + prob.variables()[4].varValue) / lpSum([prob.variables()[i].varValue for i in range(8)]) >= 0.40, "GreensRequirement"
```

This gives an error for using the + operator on NoneType, since the variables don't have values yet.  I'm just not sure exactly how to set up a constraint of this kind.  I've looked through the PuLP docs on this, but I haven't had any luck figuring out the issue.

Comment: (1) Why are you using ```ingredient_vars[i]``` before and then access later vars by ```prob.variables()[2]```? That looks a bit scary (probably some assumptions needed about ordering and co) (2) Yeah, as you have written, building a constraint while accessing a non-optimized variable-value can't work (3) This constraint of yours is probably non-convex formulated like this! Even if you would make pulp to accept it, the solver will break. You will need a different formulation.

Comment: @sascha please comment on this  https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/49792/adding-constraints-in-pulp-optimization-problems-in-python?noredirect=1#comment56928_49792

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Some remarks

- As you said yourself, you can't build constraints which are based on the value of some not-yet optimized decision-variable!

  - Constraints using `.varValue` are not possible
- I don't get the concept of `prob.variables()[2]` in general as opposed to access `ingredient_vars[i]` like before (but as i don't know what exactly `prob.variables` returns i will ignore this)
- If you replace the `.varValue` access and just use the variables directly, you are building a constraint with a *division* which is not linear and pulp will not accept this

  - Even if pulp would accept this, the solver won't be able to solve this (LP-solver)

### What to do

We need to:

- build a **linear-constraint** to represent your ratio-constraint

### Theory

We use the reformulation described in the documentation of [lpsolve](http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.5/) [here](http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.1/ratio.htm). An excerpt:

[image]
 <sup>*Screenshot of lpsolve's documentation (http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.1/ratio.htm)*</sup>

### In practice

**Remark**: As i'm unfamiliar with the `prob.variables()[2]`-like access of variables and too lazy to check the docs, i'm guessing here that *greens are: LETTUCE + SPINACH*. Feel free to change it if i misunderstood this!

The constraint looks hardcoded (not nice but might be okay for your example) like this:

```
prob += (0 - 0.4) * ingredient_vars['TOMATO'] + (1 - 0.4) * ingredient_vars['LETTUCE'] + \
        (1 - 0.4) * ingredient_vars['SPINACH'] + (0 - 0.4) * ingredient_vars['CARROT'] + \
        (0 - 0.4) * ingredient_vars['SUNFLOWER'] + (0 - 0.4) * ingredient_vars['TOFU'] + \
        (0 - 0.4) * ingredient_vars['CHICKPEAS'] + (0 - 0.4) * ingredient_vars['OIL'] >= 0.0, 'GreensRequirement'
```

This is a direct translation from the formulation of lpsolve's docs. Check the assumptions we had to made!

### Example output

Two examples using exactly your code with the replaced constraint (given my assumptions of ingredients beeing green):

#### Ratio of 0.4 (described in code above)

```
('Status:', 'Optimal')
('Ingr_CARROT', '=', 0.0)
('Ingr_CHICKPEAS', '=', 0.0)
('Ingr_LETTUCE', '=', 0.58548009)
('Ingr_OIL', '=', 0.0)
('Ingr_SPINACH', '=', 0.0)
('Ingr_SUNFLOWER', '=', 0.0)
('Ingr_TOFU', '=', 0.87822014)
('Ingr_TOMATO', '=', 0.0)
('Total kCal of Ingredients per salad = ', 114.75409824)
```

#### Ratio of 0.9

```
('Status:', 'Optimal')
('Ingr_CARROT', '=', 0.0)
('Ingr_CHICKPEAS', '=', 0.0)
('Ingr_LETTUCE', '=', 4.4146501)
('Ingr_OIL', '=', 0.0)
('Ingr_SPINACH', '=', 0.0)
('Ingr_SUNFLOWER', '=', 0.0)
('Ingr_TOFU', '=', 0.49051668)
('Ingr_TOMATO', '=', 0.0)
('Total kCal of Ingredients per salad = ', 129.4964032)
```